# Is there a way to make Outlook skip the first attempt to autodiscover?

Tags: outlook

Outlook's autodiscover process, which is great, first tries to send a POST request to `ourdomain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml` but `ourdomain.com` is actually our website - we use office365 as our exchange server.  Normally, this would only result in a bunch of 404 errors that we could gladly ignore. Unfortunately, our web platform is configured to redirect 404 errors to the internal search engine, so when this request is made, it attempts to serve `ourdomain.com/search?autodiscover+autodiscover+xml` which adds an unwanted burden to our web server.

How can we get outlook to skip this step in the autodiscover process and move on to autodiscover.outlook.com?  I know I can deny any request to the location `autodiscover`, but I was hoping there was a more graceful way of handling this.

Comment: Have a look here - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2612922

Comment: @joeqwerty that's probably the answer I need.  Dunno why my google-fu was failing